# What is the magnetic effect of a spinning charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A changing electric field produces a magnetic field, but if the electric field is spherical, this would mean that the field strength around the electric charge would be independent of such rotation, so my question is: does a spinning spherically symmetrical electric charge create a magnetic field?

Comment: Magnetic field aren't only caused by changing electric fields, a spinning non-pointlike charged object constitutes a current.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any spinning charged object has a magnetic moment that produces a magnetic field. The magnetic moment of a spinning object is given in terms its angular momentum as
${\vec\mu}=G{\vec L}$, where $G$ is called the gyromagnetic ratio. This is described in any electromagnetism textbook